# Does youtube provide video "Album" listing in their API or Not?

Tags: android, json, youtube-api

I working on youtube API.

like : you tube provide such keyword **"Top rating", "channel", "most visited", "Relevance"**  just like that **album**.

For an example album name :*"My Own Lane" in this album number of video song available*

I read on youtube and google but not getting the result. I stuck in a point that "Ablum" keyword.

Does youtube provide album details in their API or not ?

Please suggest me IS THIS POSSIBLE OR NOT ?

Thanks

Comment: What is "album section"?

Comment: like : you tube provide such keyword "Top rating", "channel", "most visited", "Relevance" ... just like that album. For an example album name :"My Own Lane" in this album number of video song available  @henry4343

Comment: I also edited my question. please have a look on that @henry4343